# Keeping only one collapse open in Angular Bootstrap UI

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

Right now my view looks like this:

```
            <tr data-ng-repeat="subtopic in vm.subtopics">
              <td data-ng-click="subtopic.isCollapsed = !subtopic.isCollapsed">{{subtopic.name}}
              <div data-ng-repeat="content in vm.contents" uib-collapse="subtopic.isCollapsed">
              <div>{{content.data}}</div>
            </div>
            </td>
             </tr>
```

It generates a list of subtopics, along with its contents. When I click on one of the subtopics, it either collapse or opens the content. However, I want to open only one content at a time. I know that I can do this with an accordion, but I don't want to have to use an accordion in this case. Is there a way to do this with the `uib-collapse` directive?

Comment: Why don't you want to use accordion? I mean, thats exactly what it is made for.